# как добавить в print() окно текст

Tags: javascript

нужно распечатать конкретный контент на странице, проблема в том что когда я добавляю этот контент до окна print я перезаписываю основную свою страницу  как это можно исправить
js:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnPrint", function() {
        var selectCont = document.querySelector('#codesList'),
            liActive = selectCont.querySelectorAll('li'),
            name,
            content,
            elem;
        for (var i = 0; liActive.length > i; i++) {
            name = liActive[i].getElementsByClassName("list-name")[0].textContent;
            content = liActive[i].getElementsByClassName("list-content")[0].textContent;
            elem += "<div><h2>" + name + "</h2><div class='content'>" + content + "</div></div>";
            document.body.innerHTML = elem;
        }
        window.print();
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Видимость элементов на странице можно регулировать с помощью `media print`:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#btnPrint", function() {
  window.print();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.onprint {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  .onpage {
    display: none;
  }
  .onprint {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="onpage">Что видно на странице
  <a href="#" id="btnPrint">Print</a></div>
<div class="onprint">Что видно при печати</div>
```